# How to stretch the navbar items of bootstrap-vue till the edge?

Tags: css, vue.js, gridview, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to stretch the navbar link the end when the screen'width is greater than 1080px. But current bootstrap default navbar can only stretch until around 1080px. How should I make it till then end. I guess Bootstrap 4 uses flex system instead of grid. Maybe this is the reason I can't override it.

[image: Current page]

```
<template>
  <section>
      <b-navbar class="nonauth-bar" toggleable="lg" type="dark">
        <b-navbar-brand href="home"><img src="../assets/nobo_small.svg" alt="Nobo logo"></b-navbar-brand>

        <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>

        <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>

          <!-- Right aligned nav items -->
          <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
            <b-nav-item><router-link to="about" class="nav-link nav-link-grow-up">About</router-link></b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item><router-link to="login" class="nav-link nav-link-grow-up">Login</router-link></b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item><router-link to="signup" class="nav-link nav-link-grow-up">SignUp</router-link></b-nav-item>
          </b-navbar-nav>
        </b-collapse>
      </b-navbar>
  </section>
```

Comment: I think we need a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `b-navbar`stretches 100% by default. You must've placed it inside something which is limiting its width. Probably an element with the class `container`

Comment: Yeah, no container in there. I think ml-auto only stretches in a certain width.

Comment: ml-auto means margin-left auto

Comment: You must have a style bound to `section` that is limiting it's width, or the navbar component is being placed inside a `b-container` or element with the container class, by the looks of it.

Comment: What CSS rules are bound to class `noauth-bar`? What does Chrome Devtools inspector show as being rendered and the styles being applied? Are you using a 3rd party CSS theme?

Comment: nonauth-bar class is just for background-color. But, section is inside of header container. That header container is inside of div container.

Comment: Problem is solved. It is because of navbar container is inside of another container. In vue.js, I think <section> must be carefully used.

Comment: `<section>` doesn't have any style overrides in default Bootstrap v4 CSS (it's CSS rules are similar to `<div>`).